# do automatic traversal on nested json file on typescript and get the key value on that nested json and translate

Tags: json, readfile

I am working related to translate a file from english to another language, reading line by line via fs.readSync becomes easier and log.

One of my blockers is I need to translate a line per line update from google translate api for example

`{{"common":"status": "regular""age": "27""hobbies": {"art": "painting""frequency": "daily"}}... (many more)`

I just want to translate the values from json data but found it difficult to map them expected is

```
{{"common":"status": "regular" <_translate regular, painting and daily"age": "27"hobbies": {"art": "painting""frequency": "daily"}}
```

Does anyone can help me? Thank you and advance!

tried to split the data and parse to object but still challenges